# Short code format for cat tagging when posting from email

Tags: shortcode

I thought I read that when you send in a post via email you can add the category tag with a short code. So I try this with something like

```
[my-category-name]
```

But all that does is print the literal with brackets.

I must be missing something obvious.

Anyone know, offhand?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is only a feature in wordpress.com blogs.  You probably want to use a plugin like [Postie](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postie/) to get the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks will check it out I am using Jetpack Post by Email so thought it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I had the format wrong. It works as [category foo,foo2] adding to both cats or creating one if it didn't already exist. Ta.

Comment: You can accept your own answer (by clicking the check mark) after 48 hours.